# Car ferries time distance

Tags: online-resources, automobiles, ferries

How does google maps calculate time and distance when auto ferries are included in route in route provided

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Google mapping methodologies.

Answer (score 3):

Ferries generally follow a timetable (departing and arriving et predetermined times) and a specific route.

Google Maps has a database of the known ferry routes that contains the lengths of various routes, the time can easily be calculated from the timetable. Both numbers are then included in the driving directions.

Comment: At least in northern Europe, e.g. for the ferries between the Scandinavian countries, the durations for the ferry crossings listed by Google Maps are not consistent with the time tables.

Comment: Last time i checked, it was up to the transport providers to upload and maintain their timetables to google maps to get them listed on the website. I'm sure there are some automated tools that would re-upload the data every time it changes, but this does not mean all the transport providers use them...